# Adding view to a list content type - document set - SharePoint Online - PnP

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, document-set, pnp

I'm trying to add a view to a specific document set in a list.

Fist I'm adding a the view to the list..

```
Add-SPOView -List "Demo List" -Title "Demo View" -Fields "Title","Address"
```

But how do I add it to the specific content type in the list?

I've tried to use

```
Get-SPOContentType -Identity "contenttypeName" -List "Demo List"
```

but then I get this error..

> Get-SPOContentType : The 'Name' member cannot be used in the expression.

I'm using PnP , see [Pnp](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP)

Comment: These are not default cmdlets from Sharepoint Online Management Shell. They are either your custom ones or from some other source. Can you post the code behind them? It would shed some light on what part exactly is throwing the error

Comment: @grisha I'm using PnP, look here https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP . I'm maby planning to send a fix